# Move tables backup to local

Tags: mysql, database, sdi

I had a dropped a database by mistake, but I still have the 3 extensions of my tables inside the database (MYD, MYI and sdi), when I move these files to "/usr/local/var/mysql/MY_DATABASE" inside MacOs, and I go into phpMyadmin or MySQL, I could not find the table, is there a way to backup my tables inside my database?

Answer (score 0):

You can restore tables (orphan included) following instructions provided in MySQL documentation : https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-troubleshooting-datadict.html

Comment: I even don't have the fields name to create it using MySQL command

Comment: Did you have any backup of your database ? then, if you are not able to recover from that situation, you have learn something super important : make backups regularly. And you can use design modeling tools so you keep your datamodel separate from your databases, so you always have the ddl code to restore next time, even from MYD, MYI and SDI files if any. Sorry but I can not help much more here. Maybe a DBA could, but not sure at all. Examples of design modeling tools : MySQL Workbench, Oracle SQL Developer, Skipper, Rational Rose (but last two I've written are expensive for a starter in dev)

Comment: In some IDE you'll have great databases integrations. In Eclipse (free) or Intellij Idea Ultimate (paid) I am able to design datamodels with some plugins. And get DDL too.
Free solution for commandline usage is mysqldump, so you can make your backups with a bash script every hour/day/week/month depending how critical these datas are for your code / work.

Comment: Thanks guys, I learned something new

Comment: @newCoder so you can give a +1 at least.